# Why is my or-spec only valid for one of the given specs?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Consider the following spec for a text or a link layer port number:

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as spec])

(spec/def ::text (spec/and string? not-empty))
(spec/valid? ::text "a")                ; => true
(spec/valid? ::text "")                 ; => false
(spec/def ::port (spec/and pos-int? (partial > 65535)))
(spec/valid? ::port 4)                  ; => true
(spec/valid? ::port 0)                  ; => false
(spec/def ::text-or-port (spec/or ::text ::port))
(spec/valid? ::text-or-port 5)          ; => true
(spec/valid? ::text-or-port "hi")       ; => false
```

For some reason it only accepts port-numbers and not text, why would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understanding this problem can be found in in the [documentation](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec/or) and using `spec/conform`.

```
(spec/conform ::text-or-port 5)
; => [:user/text 5]
```

The problem is that `clojure.spec.alpha/or` has an API which is dissimmilar to `clojure.core/or` which given two arguments returns the first truthy one:

```
(#(or (string? %) (integer? %)) 5)      ; => true
(#(or (string? %) (integer? %)) "")     ; => true
(#(or (string? %) (integer? %)) :a)     ; => false
```

Rather it takes pairs of labels and specs/predicates. And since even namespaced keywords are accepted as labels the `::text-or-port` spec given in the OP matched only that which passed the requirements for `::port` and gave it the label `::text`. Below is a correct spec for that which we want to match:

```
(spec/def ::text-or-port (spec/or :text ::text
                                  :port ::port))
(spec/valid? ::text-or-port "hi")       ; => true
(spec/valid? ::text-or-port 10)         ; => true
```